# PostGIS, Is possible to create a Polygon from some Points

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial-query

Well,

I used to create Points or Polygons from latitude and longitud. Using something like that:

```
ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT("+longitud+" "+latitud+")' ,4326),23030)
```

But on that moment my source are geometry values of thousands of points, and I would like to create a geometry Polygon value from them. But I don´t know if it is possible.

Also I have UTM coordinates(mine is 30 S), but I think that starting from geometry would be easier.

If someone could help me, I would be so gratefull.

Thanks

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/26923/12379

Answer (score 2):

You can collect an array of `point`, cast to `geometry[]`, and use `ST_MakeLine`.

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine( ARRAY[ point(1,2), point(3,4), point(5,6) ]::geometry[] ));
```